# ndk build_static_library make: Nothing to be done for `all'

Tags: android, android-ndk

I meet a problem when I build the libjpeg on android in eclipse. The jni contains Android.mk as follow:

```
    LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
    include $(CLEAR_VARS)
    LOCAL_MODULE    := hello-jni
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hello-jni.c
    #LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/jpeg8d-master
    #LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libjpeg
    include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
    #include $(LOCAL_PATH)/jpeg8d-master/Android.mk
```

The jpeg8d is the source code I download from [github](https://github.com/folecr/jpeg8d). The android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
# ------------------------------------------------------------------
# Static library for Cocos
# ------------------------------------------------------------------
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := cocos_jpeg_static
LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME := libjpeg
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
    jcapimin.c jcapistd.c jccoefct.c jccolor.c jcdctmgr.c jchuff.c \
    jcinit.c jcmainct.c jcmarker.c jcmaster.c jcomapi.c jcparam.c \
    jcprepct.c jcsample.c jctrans.c jdapimin.c jdapistd.c \
    jdatadst.c jdatasrc.c jdcoefct.c jdcolor.c jddctmgr.c jdhuff.c \
    jdinput.c jdmainct.c jdmarker.c jdmaster.c jdmerge.c \
    jdpostct.c jdsample.c jdtrans.c jerror.c jfdctflt.c jfdctfst.c \
    jfdctint.c jidctflt.c jidctfst.c jidctint.c jquant1.c \
    jquant2.c jutils.c jmemmgr.c jcarith.c jdarith.c jaricom.c

# Use the no backing store memory manager provided by
# libjpeg. See install.txt
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += \
    jmemnobs.c

LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)
include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

ndk-build give the tips :

> make: Nothing to be done for `all'.

But if I Set the jpeg8d Android.mk   `BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY`,I get the `libjpeg.so`.
I don't know why. Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 1):

Solution:
You can redefine the library name by the `LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME`. In my problem, I have set the `LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME=libjpeg`, but I don't add the 
`APP_MODULES:=cocos_jpeg_static` (remember `cocos_jpeg_staic` is the `LOCAL_MODULE` not the `LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME`) into the `Application.mk` which is  in the *jni* directory not in the *jpeg8d-master* directory.

I generate the `libjpeg.a` when i add this line into the `Appliction.mk`

```
APP_MODULES:=cocos_jpeg_static
```